# Workaround for SharePoint 2016 where users are unable to log in from Apple iOS devices when connecting using https

Tags: ios, sharepoint, https, sharepoint-2016

The issue is that users trying to connect to a SharePoint 2016 site using https will be continually prompting for credentials when browsing using an Apple iOS devices (iPhone, iPad, etc).

We have spoken to Microsoft about this issue and appears to be a known problem and came back to us with the following response.

> This issue occurs as the SharePoint Authentication is not compatible
>   with the IOS
>
> As of now this issue has been reported but the change is required from
>   the Apple end, such that the IOS accepts the SharePoint
>   Authentication.

They recommended a few work arounds, but it appears that there are a lot of cases with similar problems, so I was just wondering what work around others are using, until a fix is put in place.

- Using Http url for SharePoint
- Using a Web Application Proxy for SharePoint https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sambetts/2015/07/01/sharepoint-server-and-web-application-proxy-continued/

The current work around for me is to use a web proxy but this pain as it needs to be updated on each device for each connection.

Comment: Was this problem introduced in SharePoint 2016 on-prem? I don't have any problems with S2013, but cannot login to SP2016. Is there any official text that says that SP2016 does not work with iOS?

Comment: I had no issues with 2013, I upgraded a site from 2013 to 2016. I have an email from Microsoft support confirming the issue.

Comment: Well. I guess we can tell Microsoft how to fix the issue now :) See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue with HTTPS and SharePoint 2016. 
The issue was solved by disabling HTTP/2 for IIS 10. I had to create two registry keys: under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters`

`EnableHttp2Tls REG_DWORD 0`

`EnableHttp2Cleartext REG_DWORD 0`

**Update**

This should only take effect after you restart the server.

Comment: Tried this added the keys, IISRESET, still the same sadly.

Comment: IISReset is not enough. you need to restart the server